# Pytest-xdist cannot run after being packaged with pyinstaller

Tags: python, pytest, pyinstaller, pytest-xdist

This Python script can be run locally, but after being packaged with pyinstaller, it has been stuck in an endless loop. Is there a problem with packaging?

```
Python 3.9.6
pyinstaller==5.13.0
pytest==7.4.0
pytest-xdist==3.3.1
```

My code:

test_case.py

```py
import pytest
 
def test_example1():
    assert 1==1

def test_example2():
    assert 1 + 1 == 2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pytest.main(["-n", "1"])
```

[image]

test_case.spec

```py
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(
    ['test_case.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[
        ('D:/Anaconda/envs/python3.9/Lib/site-packages/apipkg', './apipkg'), 
        ('D:/Anaconda/envs/python3.9/Lib/site-packages/apipkg-3.0.2.dist-info', './apipkg-3.0.2.dist-info'),
        ('D:/Anaconda/envs/python3.9/Lib/site-packages/pytest_xdist-3.3.1.dist-info', './pytest_xdist-3.3.1.dist-info'), 
        ('D:/Anaconda/envs/python3.9/Lib/site-packages/xdist', './xdist'),
        ('D:/Anaconda/envs/python3.9/Lib/site-packages/execnet', './execnet'), 
        ('D:/Anaconda/envs/python3.9/Lib/site-packages/execnet-2.0.2.dist-info', './execnet-2.0.2.dist-info'), 
        ],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    [],
    name='test_case',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)
```

[image]

It was always running before.

I have tried using different versions of packages, but none of them worked.

Comment: I have the same problem. Can anyone answer?

Answer (score 0):

I asked to the pyinstaller support and here you can find an answer to your question: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/8283

I then wanted to make pyinstaller work with the BaseCase class and I proceeded like this (I wanted to include aaa.py in my bundle):

```
bundle_dir = getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
path_to_help = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(bundle_dir,'aaa.py'))

BaseCase.main(__name__, path_to_help, -n2, "-o", "log_cli=true", "--log-cli-level=INFO", "--uc", "--uc-cdp", "--pls=none", "--sjw", "--block-images", "--disable-warnings", "-p no:warnings", "--no-header", "--no-summary", "--quiet", "--maxfail=1")
```

In the BaseCase.main I had to modify this method:

```
subprocess.call(
   ["python", "-m", "pytest", file, "-s", *all_args]
)
```

because the sys.executable (instead of "python") referred to the .exe (done by Pyinstaller)